# Drive auto mounting as read only (errors=remount-ro)

Tags: ubuntu, mount

My system (12.04 Ubuntu LTS) is auto-mounting as read only and I have no idea why.

Output of fstab:

```
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=28db2489-f60e-456c-9efd-7a961f3e970a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=106e4470-d734-4cec-98a6-c7859aaedf18 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Output of mount:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
I have searched all night including: Ubuntu 12.04 SSD root frequent random read only file system
```

I have no idea why this is going on. I did run fsck at boot and it didn't find errors.

The disk is fine (500GB, user 38GB)

Answer (score 1):

The output from `mount` shows that it is being mounted `rw` and not read-only.

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
```

What you are seeing indicates that if the system encounters errors it will remount as read-only.

Comment: Here is what I am seeing(this is my question), which lead me to the read only: http://askubuntu.com/questions/401803/ubuntu-corrupted-log-files?noredirect=1#comment515547_401803